# Writing a recommendation letter for student with low GPA

Tags: graduate-admissions, advisor, recommendation-letter

I have an undergraduate student who has been working in my lab for quite some time, doing relatively advanced work and has even been able to mentor other students in getting up to speed in the workings of the lab and the methods we use. I never had this student in a class, but they approached me in their second year asking if I had any opportunities and I was happy to provide an unpaid opportunity and the following year a student job for them after seeing their exceptional work.

This student is now applying to graduate school and has asked me to write them a recommendation letter, and I said I would be happy to do so since the student has demonstrated competence and has even started asking quite interesting research questions related to our work. As part of the recommendation process I always ask for the application materials, including transcripts, personal statement and so on. Upon looking at the transcripts I found out the student has a very bad academic history and has even recently been on academic probation. They got C's in classes closely related to our subject (but taught by people I don't know well in the department). I'm not sure what to think or whether to include that as part of my recommendation letter, or to ignore it overall?

Comment: Can you ask the student for permission to discuss them with the other faculty? But, in any case, if you think they have the knowledge even without the grades, you can certainly say that. You might also ask the student about the grades, of course. There may have been external issues you don't know about.

Comment: This is exactly what recommendation letters are *for* is so that the evaluators can learn more about an "exceptional" student beyond grades, which of course can vary widely between faculty, departments, universities, countries, and continents.

Comment: @Buffy Yes, I can do both, but going into that conversation I'm not exactly sure what sort of questions I should ask - if there are circumstances I don't know about, should that effect my letter? And also should I advise the student that their chances of admission are very low given their grades despite their clear research ability?

Comment: You made a mistake in asking for the transcript, and they made a mistake giving it to you. You job is to speak from first hand experience. You're not a part of the candidate filtering process. Now you'll have a tough time speaking in an unbiased way.

Comment: As others have said, you should probably sit down with the student and talk about this.  One topic of that discussion should be strategizing his application package.  This student may fare better applying to a Master's than a PhD, because there's less of a risk that extensive resources will be put into them.

Comment: In your situation, I'd write that I'm aware of the student's poor grades but that what I've seen in my lab is very different. I'd go on to provide the information in the first part of your question, with more details about this student's work. Your offering a paid job after seeing the first year's performance is, I think, important because it's tangible evidence that you're not just saying nice things in the letter; you've put your money where your mouth is.

Comment: I think you should change this in future. Do not ask for material that would be evaluated nevertheless. You have been wrongly doing (not personal, I see that your aim was positive). The point is that a recommendation letter should be potentially able to reverse a verdict. That is why it is asked or welcomed in an evaluation process.

Comment: You comment based upon your interaction and you don't speculate beyond that.

Answer (score 30):

When I write letters for undergrads (in math, in the U.S.), I usually aim to speak exactly and only about things I know from first-hand experience. For that matter, transcripts (whether high-GPA or low) are usually part of the application, so second-hand comments from me add little.

Now and then, I *am* surprised to learn that a student of whom I think quite highly has had some rough spots earlier. I can only infer that they've done a great job of turning themselves around, and I'm happy to vouch for the positive things they're doing.

Comment: I was very surprised! The problem is that it was poor performance throughout, the grades didn't really get better.

Comment: @RJWilliams, hm, ... Does not bode well. Still, I somewhat prefer the evidence of my own eyes... Well, bad grades throughout will be visible in the transcript, so you/we don't have to "pile on". I'd just not refer to that and let the admissions cte reach their own conclusions.

Comment: @RJWilliams It might be worthwhile talking to the student about why their performance is poor.  Perhaps they are the kind of person who cannot motivate themselves to write up and submit their homework, but nevertheless studies hard and learns the subject well.  I would say a low GPA in this case is indicative of a failure of grades to measure learning, not really any fundamental flaw in the student themselves (other than an intolerance for work they do not find meaningful, if that can be considered a flaw).

Comment: As a student, I second the comment by @StevenGubkin that grades don't say as much about skill in the topic as they say about skill in getting good grades. I have always said that the reason my grades were just a bit above "sufficient" was that I preferred learning interesting stuff over what I know they will test. This semester I have tested that hypothesis by aiming for good grades instead (wasn't as fun though) and I got two perfect grades and another one higher than all of my previous grades, yet feel I learned less overall.

Comment: @RJWilliams As someone who has graduated with a low GPA, there are several people (including me) in my college (very competitive one) who joined FAANGs (Google, Apple, Facebook) graduating with 2.x GPAs. These people (including me) consistently focused on things apart from academics which paid off in the long term (research, CP). My advice would be to recommend based on your experience with the student. He might be relying on you to give him a glowing recommendation, having focused on your lab. I suggest you have a frank conversation with him and understand what his priorities are.

Comment: `I can only infer that they've done a great job of turning themselves around` Or that they just didn't put effort into coursework.  It's possible to learn the material well but score poorly simply by not turning in assignments.  Especially in courses with a 70% or 80% weight for the final exam it doesn't really make sense to do a semester's worth of assignments when you can walk away with a B- or C for just three hours' work if you don't particularly need the tedious exercise of doing assignments in order to learn the material.

Answer (score 21):

This answer may be limited to the US and other places where letters of recommendation have quite a bit of importance. I realize that this isn't a universal.

If you think that a student is performing beyond what the grades would indicate you could, and should, say that. You don't need to explain bad grades, nor assume that the student's chances are lessened necessarily.

Some students do relatively poorly in situations in which there are high risk tests determining the grade. They might actually know the material, but just have issues about testing.

With the student's permission to discuss them with your colleagues, you could ask if they have any evidence that the student can (and probably will) perform past what the grades might indicate.

If you talk to the student, ask why they think their grades are lower than you would have expected.

But graduate study and academic research beyond that isn't about getting grades, but about having the knowledge, skills, attitude, and perseverance to do good work. If you see that in the student you can say that the student has shown performance beyond that indicated by the GPA. Some students, of course, even have learning difficulties that make high grades much harder to achieve, even if they have the knowledge.

I would occasionally write that "I would accept this student for any research task without reservation." That can mean a lot, provided that it is actually true.

Comment: Definitely true that I trust them to handle research tasks. I'll talk to my collogues to see what they think. Should I be worried about it reflecting poorly on me as a junior rank to recommend someone who has such a poor academic record? The programs they would be applying to include many senior people in my subfield.

Comment: If you are sure of your judgement, then state it. But be aware that your recommendations affect what you can say in the future. I once recommended a student with poor scores to the doctoral program at Georgia Tech and he did marvelously well and is now faculty at an R1. OTOH I once highly recommended a top student who failed out, but I didn't realize at the time that he was dying of AIDS. I had to deal with that aspect so that my future recommendations were properly evaluated. Fortunately, I knew the faculty that received the recommendation. Not every story is happy.

Comment: @Buffy Are you saying your recommendation was substandard because the student was dying of AIDS?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie My understanding is that Buffy's recommendation was good, but the student unfortunately could not keep to her/his standards due to serious medical situation. And this had later to be explained to those who did not know about it.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, he was an excellent student in all ways and the recommendation (to a top school) reflected that. But he declined in health soon after, struggled through a year of grad studies and then died. He came back once to visit so I got  to say goodbye, at least. We lost one of our department staff to AIDS at about that time also. Sad age.

Comment: "But graduate study and academic research beyond that isn't about getting grades, but about having the knowledge, skills, attitude, and perseverance to do good work. " -- to a degree, but an admissions committee will also be very interested in whether the student will flunk out based on coursework.

Comment: @ScottSeidman but that info is already available to the committee

Comment: @Buffy Re the student who passed away: are you saying that had you known what the student was going through, you'd have *not* recommended them? I'm trying to figure out how them failing out due to no fault of their own (at least on the face of it) was somehow a bad thing: they obviously wanted to do academic work as much as they could to the end, and presumably that exactly has happened? I'm trying to get what your recommendation would be in such a case... Maybe I'm reading too much into it, but knowing if you'd have done anything differently had you known would be useful info.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, the recommendation would have been the same to the university, but my recommendation to him would have been to focus everything on staying alive. But, actually, I'm not sure that he even knew the prognosis at that moment.

Comment: @Buffy Thank you - that makes perfect sense.